# CAML query with multiple OR conditions

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml

I am using CAML query to retrieve a list of documents based on the approval status. Please see the query below - I read that it's not allowed to put more than two conditions in one condition group ( AND | OR). So I grouped only 2 OR conditions together - This does work but is returning irrelevant results ( it is also retrieving the documents with approval status = 'None') I have tried numerous ways but cannot get to what that I am looking for.

```
<Query>
   <Where>
       <Or>
       <Or>
           <eq>
               <FieldRef Name="ppprovalType" />
               <Value Type="Choice">Approve</Value>
             </eq>
             <eq>
                 <FieldRef Name="ApprovalType" />
                 <Value Type="Choice">Approve w/contingencies</Value>
             </eq>
         </Or>
         <eq>
             <FieldRef Name="ApprovalType" />
             <Value Type="Choice">Change Needed</Value>
         </eq>
       </Or>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

Also used the 'Neq' to list out the remaining statuses but didn't work either.

What is the right way to retrieve a document whose approval status is either '1' or '2' or '3'?

Answer (score 0):

As per my test, this works for me:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Or>
            <Eq>
             <FieldRef Name='ppprovalType' /><Value Type='Choice'>Approve</Value>
            </Eq>
        <Or>
         <Eq>
             <FieldRef Name='ApprovalType' /><Value Type='Choice'>Approve w/contingencies</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
             <FieldRef Name='ApprovalType' /><Value Type='Choice'>Change Needed</Value>
        </Eq>
     </Or>
 </Or>
   </Where>
</Query>
```